# How do I revert the sudo less /private/etc/cups/printers.conf command?

Tags: macos, command-line, printing, sudo, cups

I have used the above command to try and find my printer's address using the web.

Now I would like to revert this setting using terminal.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `less` is not changing anything. You exit `less` command with `q`.

Answer (score 1):

Less isn't modifying anything in your printer settings, it's just displaying the contents of the file. For example:

```
less test.txt
```

will show the contents of the test text file. If you exit using `q`, and you reopen the Terminal window, you will no longer see the IP address of the printer without using the

```
less
```

command again.